# Extension works in cli but doesn't work in apache

Tags: php, apache, command-line-interface

I'm using ZeroMQ, and it works in CLI, but doesn't work in apache.
I added extension=zmq.so in both of php.ini files (/etc/php/7.0/apache/php.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/ini.php)
But apache can't call new ZMQSocket constructor.
CLI works, but with this warning:

```
PHP Warning: Module 'zmq' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: remove zmq.so  from ini as  some times it makes a separate file at the time of installation and load it and also did you restarted apache after installation.

Comment: I did restart every time